# Shell SQLPLUS prints CLOB data twice

Tags: linux, oracle, sqlplus, ksh

I have the below code in my ksh shell script file and when i run this i get the output printed twice in the file. here the FILE_DATA is of type CLOB

```
sqlplus -s ${uidpwd} > ${DATA_FILE_NAME} << EOF 
set head off 
SET pagesize 0
SET LINESIZE 32767
SET LONGCHUNKSIZE 32767
SET LONG 320000000
SET RECSEP OFF
set SERVEROUTPUT off 
SET ECHO off
SET TRIMOUT ON
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
set termout off

set feedback off verify off heading off newpage 0
whenever OSERROR EXIT 9
whenever SQLERROR EXIT sql.SQLCODE
SELECT FILE_DATA FROM FILES WHERE ID='208';
/
exit;
EOF
```

Data:

```
"Client_id,Client_id_type,Client_Segment
1,LOCAL_ID,Individual"
```

Comment: remove / .  that is running prior sql 2x.

Comment: Oh my god.. thats so simple. yes it worked